# Using Google's App Engine with Python SDK

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I have installed the Google App Engine; the GAE launcher GUI; and the Python SDK.

I have successfully deployed a webpage using the GUI, and my test page is now viewable at the external URL.

Unfortunately, the only way I have known to do this, is to include all my HTML code in the Python .py file within the GAE directory. What I WANT to do, is to include code in my .py file that calls a separate .html file.  So far despite my best search efforts I can't understand how to write this. Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you read the documentation? It shows you exactly how to use Jinja2 templates with Python.

Comment: The GAE documentation is full of examples on how to use templating and assets, did you read through those yet?

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks for replying. I have followed the instructions of the help pages to include Jinja2 (ie adding reference to the .yaml file). However when I do this, and then try to run my web app in the GAE GUI, it fails to do so. IIeinstead of a little green circle appearing, a "!" In a warning triangle is displayed. Afterwards I can't get the web app to ru , or the browser to load the page when accessing http://localhost:8080 (the port allocated by the Google GUI).

Comment: Can you show your yaml file with jinja2 templates?

Answer (score 1):

First off, install Jinja2 using [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) in a terminal (or command line):

```
pip install jinja2
```

Secondly, include it in your app.yaml file as a library.

```
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
```

Declare a Jinja environment in your code so that you can render templates:

```
import jinja2

env = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('templates')
)
```

Now you need to create a template .html file in a 'templates' folder. If we create an "index.html" template that we want to render in code we would write:

```
template = env.get_template('index.html')
self.response.write(template.render())
```

There is obviously a lot more you can do with templates than simply render html - you can have a look at features on [Jinjas website](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/).

The process for doing all of this is better explained [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates) in the python tutorial for google app engine.

If you need an example, I have recently open sourced a google app engine application I developed on github and you can take a [look at it](https://github.com/KillaW0lf04/Photo-Nebula) for some guidance if you wish.